# Sending files from the html form to the mail

Tags: php

How should I organize the sending of attachments from the site form to the mail. I'd like to send the file from `userfile` input field and send it to the PHP script to be handled.

This is my HTML form code:

```
<form class="form-upload clearfix" action="send-resume.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="file_upload">
    <div class="download-block">
      <img src="img/form-list.svg" alt="Файл не выбран">
      <a type="button">Прикрепить файл</a>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" required>
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="send">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my PHP send script code:

```
<?php
 /* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */

/* Сам лепил, но не работает

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
 if (isset($_POST['userfile'])) {$contact_resume = $_POST['userfile'];}
*/

/* Почта */
$address = "mail@mail.ru";
/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */

    $mes = "Резюме: $contact_resume\n";
    // $mes .= "Телефон: $contact_tel\n";

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */


$HTTP_HOST = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); 
$HTTP_HOST = str_replace(array("http://","www."),"",$HTTP_HOST['host']);
$email='<'.$HTTP_HOST.'>'; // от кого

$sub='Заказ с '.$HTTP_HOST; //сабж
//echo $sub.'<br>'.$mes.'<br>'.$address;
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"; 
 $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,$headers);
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
$redicet = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Refresh: 3; url=".$redicet);
?>
    /* Почта */
    $address = "mail@mail.ru";
    /* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */

        $mes = "Резюме: $contact_resume\n";
        // $mes .= "Телефон: $contact_tel\n";

    /* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */


    $HTTP_HOST = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); 
    $HTTP_HOST = str_replace(array("http://","www."),"",$HTTP_HOST['host']);
    $email='<'.$HTTP_HOST.'>'; // от кого

    $sub='Заказ с '.$HTTP_HOST; //сабж
    //echo $sub.'<br>'.$mes.'<br>'.$address;
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"; 
     $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,$headers);
    ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
    $redicet = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    header("Refresh: 3; url=".$redicet);
    ?>
```

Comment: Stating `help me` repeatedly doesn't make us want to assist you further. The minimum length is so you describe what happens with your code and what should happen. You haven't done that yet.

Comment: Hi, you can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), it's easy to use and configure, any doubt, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you, I was unable to edit as it is "mostly code", so I had to add filler.